# How to use if else statement with Groovy?

Tags: groovy

i'm using a Groovy step with Soapui.
The following code is working well but it seems to be long and repetitive:

```
if(response.comp.type[3] == "value1")
log.info ("value1 is present")
else
log.info ("value1 is not present")

if(response.comp.bucket[3] == null)
log.info ("bucket = null")
else
log.info ("bucket is not null")

if(response.comp.cycle[3] == "new")
log.info ("settings cycle = new")
else
log.info ("settings cycle is null")
```

Is it possible to do the same in one test instead of repeating the IF and ELSE on each line.
i tried with TRY CATCH but i cannot have the stack trace of the error.

Can anyone help to reduce the code.
Thank you

Comment: As per examples, answers and comments, I'm finding this hard to generalize, seems like each case is pretty specific.

Answer (score 13):

As the fields are all different you still need to do each check but a more concise form would be:

```
log.info (response.comp.type[3] == "value1" ? "value1 is present" : "value1 is not present")
log.info (response.comp.bucket[3] == null ? "bucket = null" : "bucket is not null")
log.info (response.comp.cycle[3] == "new" ? "settings cycle = new" : "settings cycle is null")
```

With a little more effort you could reduce duplication but at the risk of making the code more difficult to read. E.g.

```
log.info "bucket ${response.comp.bucket[3] == null ? '=' : 'is not'} null"
```

As you can see, in this case at least, the second form is harder to read.

Comment: Thank you Michael, the second code, i have to create variable in properties and i will to create at least 30, it could be a solution

Comment: But the problem the response could change, so i cannot update everytime, if i can this will complicate the code

Answer (score 4):

i dont know if this will be of your preference but you can use `switch` instead of having a long `if..else` statement like:

```
def x = response.comp.type[3]
switch(x){
  case "value1" : log.info("value1 is present")
  ...
  default: log.info("value is not present")
}
```

where `x` is the value you will assign to it. and do the same for `response.comp.bucket[]` and `response.comp.cycle[]`

**Edit**

I have modified the code, declared x as the holder of the response.comp.type[3] and checks if it has the "value1".

Comment: i added this line before your code def x = new int[0,1,2,3,4,5] and this case 3: log.info("value1 is present") it's not working for me

Comment: what i meant by putting x in `response.comp.try[x]` is that the value of it depends on what you will put in it. based on your example you have `response.comp.type[3]` then you will have to put that in the switch statement like `switch(response.comp.type[3])`